# Bigquery and Tableau producing execution failure - potential slow bigquery response issue

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have an instance of Tableau and I have used its built-in connector to access BigQuery. Previously this all seemed to work well, but then it started generating errors once a report was published to Server. Having spoken to Tableau support, I refreshed the password on the server and tried again.

However, today I am having other problems (not sure if they are related to the first or not), which I hope you can help with.
In Tableau Desktop, I connect to BigQuery, and try to run a simple count(*) statement. This is failing with the message:
[Simba][Gauss] (5) Query execution failed. %1%

Not knowing what this means, I have logged on to the BigQuery sql interface https://bigquery.cloud.google.com and tried the query there.
Whilst it worked, it took over 2 minutes to return a value of 1.8million rows in the dataset.

This seems excessively high, so I am assuming that there is an issue with the table in BigQuery, and that fixing that will fix the Tableau issue.

However, I now don't know where to begin, as I am totally new to BigQuery. How should I go about troubleshooting this? It doesn't seem to happen on all tables, but what could be causing one table to be particularly slow?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: In tableau are you using the COUNT function or a Custom SQL connection? I consider that I have a lot of experience using Tableau with BigQuery. The connection with Tableau and BigQuery works fine for simple cases but if you need to do more complex stuff like blend/joins or complex calculated fields then you will experience at some point limits/errors in the connectivity between Tableau and BigQuery. Can you post the query that Tableau try to execute? You can see it in the query history in the BigQuery web interface.

Comment: For the record, I tried it using Number of Records in Tableau, but then used SELECT count(*) FROM Table in the BigQuery Browser interface.

However, I think I have discovered my problem. The table in BigQuery is highly fragmented, and I believe this might be causing my issues. Unfortunately, this leads on to another problem - how on earth do I fix this?
I can't copy the table as it fails, so I exported it to Cloud Storage (it's a JSON type file). But now I can't reimport it as I don't know how to tell BigQuery what the schema is (it just keeps complaining).